# Java: Format elements and count number of reoccurring elements in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to determine how many times each number between 0-999 has been used in the array.
Also I'm wanting to format the elements so that its always a 3 digit number. instead of '21' it would be '021', '5' would be '005'. 
Netbeans is saying to use an enhanced loop in place of for(int x=0;x

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creator of random number 0-999
    Random creator = new Random(999);

    int lotto[][] = new int[1000][2];
    int count = 0;

    for(int x=0;x<lotto.length; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < lotto[x].length; y++){
            //Fills element with random number
            lotto[x][y] = creator.nextInt(999);
        }
    }
    //Place holder to print out array
    for(int[] a: lotto){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

}

Edit: 
I've tried this

```
for(int x=0;x<lotto.length; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < lotto[x].length; y++){
            //Fills element with random number
            ++lotto[creator.nextInt(999)][creator.nextInt(999)];
        }
    }
 for(int j=0; j < lotto.length;j++){
        System.out.println(j +""+ lotto[j]);
 }
```

But now the program doesnt run. I think the ++lotto is right to count how many time that element is used.

Edit 2:

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int x=0;x<lotto.length;x++){
        for(int y=0; y<lotto[x].length; y++){
            list.add(lotto[x][y]);
        }
    }
    for(int x=0; x<1000; x++){
        if(list.contains(x)){
            int index = 0;
            int countList = 0;
            while(index!= -1){
                countList++;
                list.remove(index);
                index = list.indexOf(x);
            }
            System.out.println(x +" Hit "+ countList + "time(s)");
        }
    }
```

When the array prints out, theres 1 less the number of found elements in the array as what the list is printing out.

UPDATE: 
For some reason now the source below to count the list, the number doesnt match the count of the number of times the user's input is. ie: user inputs 200, it counts 200 was used twice but the list only prints out it was found once

```
for(int x=0;x<lotto.length;x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < lotto[x].length; y++){
            if(lotto[x][y]== lottery)
                count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you use a traditional for-loop or a for-each loop. Don't worry about it. However, tell us what you have tried in order to accomplish your two goals (counting the numbers and formatting the numbers).

Comment: Like many programmers will say it is a matter of taste. One difference between them is the performance but if you don't implement a very big applications with many for loops (also nested for loops) etc. you will not recognize it.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start really. I've read about mapping and lists, but dont understand how to implement that

Comment: I've just been able to add a search ability to see if a number is found in the array. Think I want to focus more on the counting the number of times a number is found. 000 found 0 times. 124 is found 1 time. Etc.

Comment: Why are you using a two-dimensional array?

Comment: Because the 2 columns are for two different times when lottery numbers are done. Mid day and evening. Plus my assignment calls for 2d

Answer (score 0):

You could load your 2D Array in a 1D List to count occurences of each number between 0 and 999. Hence you would benefit of methods of ArrayList. 
Code for counting :

```
    int occurences[] = new int[1000];
    int max = 0;

    for(int x=0; x<1000; x++){
        if (liste.contains(x)) {
            int index = liste.indexOf(x);
            int count = 0;
            while(index != -1){
                count++;
                liste.remove(index);
                index = liste.indexOf(x);
            }
            occurences[x] = count;
            if (count >= max) max = count;
        }
        else  occurences[x] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < occurences.length; i++){
        if (occurences[i] == max)
        System.out.println("valeur " + i + " --> " + max);
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your input. I'm also wanting to output the number that are not in the array. So if number 100 isnt in the array, it counts it as 0. Seems that code is only displaying the numbers that are in the array. In other words, list all the numbers within the range of 0-999 and count how many times each number shows up regardless if it was used

Comment: Also I notice that with this its always counting 1 more than what is actually in the array.

Comment: You're right Chris, I've just fixed the 2 bugs in the source code upstairs from this comment.

Comment: Hmm.. when Im using my for statement to count how many times the user's number is found in the array, its always 1 more than your source. Is there a way to add the ability to find the most occurring number in the list?

Comment: Just read my brand new solution. Your bug come from **index** that you initialise to **0** rather than initialising it to **list.indexOf(x)**. This wrong way make you delete just list[0] for the first recursion. And if your first occurence of x is beyond it will remain

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help. Now on to figure out counting the most occurred number

Comment: That's easyer to count the most occurred number. Ask for help if you need

Comment: Ya I'm stuck implementing it.
I tried adding within the for loop. 
int max =0;
if(list.indexOf(x) > 0)
list.indexOf(x)= max;

Comment: I've just implemented what you need using an array for storing number of occurences in case of several numbers have a same max

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I'm understanding this correctly, you need a 2D array with 1000 rows and 2 columns. You assign a random number into each column, so 2000 values all in the range of 0-999. It seems like you're doing that part right already, but what you still need is to count how many occurrences of each number (0-999) there are?

If so you should create a second array ie: `int[] countOccurences = new int[1000]`, then in the for loop that puts the random int into the 2D array, you would want to change it to `int tmp = creator.nextInt(999)` and assign that to the 2D array the same way then also do `countOccurences[tmp]+=1`. Then for example if there were 2 occurences of the int 47, then countOccurences[47] would equal 2.